# sql query for unique set of record

Tags: sql

i have one sql query as -

```
SELECT name_1, dpid_clid, city 
 FROM dts_master_dividend 
 WHERE upper(name_1) like upper('%') 
   AND dpid_clid like upper('IN30290243450560%')
 ORDER BY name_1 asc, dpid_clid asc, dividend_type desc
```

It displays the results as -

```
ABHINAV  BHARTI IN30290243450560    PUNE
ABHINAV  BHARTI IN30290243450560    DELHI
ABHINAV  BHARTI IN30290243450560    PUNE
ABHINAV  DUBEY  IN30290243450560    PUNE
ABHINAV  BHARTI IN30290243450560    PUNE
```

But I want my result as  -

```
ABHINAV  BHARTI IN30290243450560    PUNE
ABHINAV  BHARTI IN30290243450560    DELHI
ABHINAV  DUBEY  IN30290243450560    PUNE
```

That means only unique set of record..
How can I get it?

Comment: sorry for the delay to reply.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select name_1, dpid_clid, city 
from dts_master_dividend 
where upper(name_1) like upper('%') and dpid_clid like upper('IN30290243450560%')
group by name_1, dpid_clid ,city
```

Comment: group by always requires same names as in select, so in group by use name_1 as well.

Comment: still +1 for different thinking than others.

Comment: Abhinav:) I think no need to group by name filed. enough these two fileds

Comment: that would work only when i have different names.  otherwise you have to.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select distinct name_1, dpid_clid, city
  from dts_master_dividend
 where upper(name_1) like upper('%')
   and dpid_clid like upper('IN30290243450560%')
 order by name_1 asc, dpid_clid asc, dividend_type desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name_1, dpid_clid, city 
 FROM dts_master_dividend 
 WHERE upper(name_1) like upper('%') 
   AND dpid_clid like upper('IN30290243450560%')
 ORDER BY name_1 asc, dpid_clid asc, dividend_type desc
```

This removes duplicate rows from the resultset. For the MySQL docu see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Comment: I don't know whether I am true or not but i noticed this---- I can't use order by for those column names which are not in the select. so either I have to remove `dividend_type desc` from order by or have to add `dividend_type` in the select. after that it is working fine.

Comment: @Abhinav In that case just add the additional column. Most of the time it wont have a substantial influence on your query performance ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT distinct name_1, dpid_clid, city 
 FROM dts_master_dividend 
 WHERE upper(name_1) like upper('%') 
   AND dpid_clid like upper('IN30290243450560%')
 ORDER BY name_1 asc, dpid_clid asc
```

Comment: I don't know whether I am true or not but i noticed this---- I can't use order by for those column names which are not in the select. so either I have to remove `dividend_type desc` from order by or have to add `dividend_type` in the select. after that it is working fine.

Comment: @Abhinav add the column or remove it from the order by, you are right indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your database server, but the standard way to do this is to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT [columns] FROM [table].
```

So try putting a DISTINCT in your query

```
select distinct name_1, dpid_clid, city from dts_master_dividend where upper(name_1) like  upper('%') and dpid_clid like upper('IN30290243450560%') order by name_1 asc, dpid_clid asc, dividend_type desc
```

See the [w3schools page on select distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the `upper(name_1) like upper('%')` and instead of `upper('IN30290243450560%')` just use `'IN30290243450560%'`.

So your query should look like -

```
SELECT DISTINT name_1, dpid_clid, city
FROM dts_master_dividend
WHERE dpid_clid like 'IN30290243450560%'
ORDER BY name_1 asc, dpid_clid asc, dividend_type desc;
```